# Why is an error given when entering text to be processed with C

Tags: c, cs50

I'm working with C, and not sure why the code is not working.

The following code is supposed to read the sentence and print out what grade level it is, based on the number of words.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
    
int letter;
int word;
int sentence;
    
   
int main(void)
{
    // prompt the user with the question
    string article = get_string("What's the article?: ");

    // set the length of article
    int n = strlen(article);
    
    // add +1 if the article starts with alphanumeric letter
    if (isalnum(article[0]))
    {
        word = 1;
    }

    // count words
    for (int i = 0; i < n;  i++)
    {
        // count letters
        if (isalnum(article[i]))
        {
            letter++;
        }

        // count words
        if (i < n - 1 && isspace(article[i]) && isalnum(article[i + 1]))
        {
            word++;
        }

        // count sentences
        if (i > 0 && (article[i] == '!' || article[i] == '?' || article[i] == '.') && isalnum(article[i - 1]))
        {
            sentence++;
        }
    }
    // calculate Coleman-Liau index
    int grade = 0.0588 * (100 * letter / word) - 0.296 * (100 * sentence / word) - 15.8;
    
    // debugger
    printf("Letters: %i\n Words: %i\n Sentences: %i\n", letter, word, sentence);
    
    // print result
    if (grade <= 1)
    {
        printf("Before Grade 1\n");
    }
    else if (grade < 16)
    {
        printf("Grade %i\n", grade);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Grade 16+\n");
    }
}
```

To test the code I entered the sentence:

```sh
One fish. Two fish. Red fish. Blue fish.
```

And got the error:

```sh
    bash: One: command not found
```

I do not know why the command is not found?

The expected response should be "before grade 1".

Comment: Did you compile the program and run it? Were there any errors when you compiled?

Comment: It looks like you're just typing input into the shell, not your running program.

Answer (score 1):

You need to:

1. Compile your code in the console/terminal (see [abelenky's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62806996/6501141) or [this article](https://www.edureka.co/blog/how-to-compile-c-program-in-command-prompt/) for more info)

   - This step takes the source code file that you posted, and converts it into a format that can be executed by a computer.
2. Run the compiled executable file in the console/terminal by typing in the name of the executable file.
3. When it runs, it will print out `What's the article?`
4. After that point, you can then enter the phrase you want the program to analyze

---

#### Explanation of the Error

When you entered `One fish. Two fish. Red fish. Blue fish.` at the Bash prompt, your program was not running. Bash interpreted this text as a command that you wanted to run on your computer. It first saw the word `One` and searched for an internal command or a file called `One` in your computer that it could execute. There is no built-in command for `One`, and bash didn't find a "One" file to execute, so it reported the Error `bash: One: command not found`.

Answer (score -1):

```
gcc MyFile.c

./a.out

What's the article?: One fish. Two fish. Red fish. Blue fish.
```

Comment: While this is probably the right solution, a bit more elaboration would be helpful. For example, I wouldn't expect the code to compile cleanly...